# How to get email id of user in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I have following code to connect with LDAP which is working fine for me -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

 private static final String LdapBaseDn = GlobalProps.getProperty(GlobalProps.PROP_LDAP_BASEDN); 
     private static  StringBuilder ldapQuery; 
     private static SearchControls ldapSearchControl; 

     public void setQuery(String query) {            
          ldapQuery = new StringBuilder(query);               
     } 

     public void setMaxResults(long maxResults) { 
          ldapSearchControl.setCountLimit(maxResults); 
     } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //LdapContext ctx = null;


        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = null;
        List<LdapPerson> people = new ArrayList<LdapPerson>();

        try{

        Hashtable<Object,Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "Global\\"+Util.usenam);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Util.password);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://stladdc01.global.sial.com:389"); 
        //ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

          DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            boolean result = ctx != null;
            if(ctx != null)
               ctx.close();

            System.out.println(result);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

`System.out.println(result)` is giving output of true. But I need the code to get emailID of the same user from LDAP directory. Can Anyone help me on this?

Comment: `ctx` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it, so merely printing what is essentially a constant `true` is completely pointless.

Comment: I have checked this code with wrong credentials(wrong username OR password) ctx value is printing false.But with right one its giving true.Please help me to get email-Id for for the user.

Comment: Not possible. If the credentials are wrong this code will throw an exception, not execute the null test.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please include these changes in your code and see if it works. Don't forget to pass your `username`. Hope this will give you some idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = null;
        try {
            Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "Global\\" + Util.usenam);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Util.password);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://stladdc01.global.sial.com:389");
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            if (ctx != null) {
                Test test = new Test();
                // pass your actual username here.....
                test.getUserAttributes("username", ctx);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getUserAttributes(String username, LdapContext ctx) {
        try {
            SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
            constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            /* String[] attrIDs = { "mail", "telephonenumber" }; 
             You can have multiple attributes like SN, telephonenumber, mail
            etc.. */
            String[] attrIDs = { "mail" };
            constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=YourDomain,DC=com", "sAMAccountName=" + username, constraints);
            if (answer.hasMore()) {
                Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
                System.out.println("mail " + attrs.get("mail"));
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Invalid User");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For more information you can refer to these links:
http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/09/24/retrieve-basic-user-attributes-from-active-directory-using-ldap-in-java.html

http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-java.html

Comment: You now need to state what the changes are from the OP's code, and why they fix the problem. Mere links are not an answer, and neither is mere code.

Comment: Thanks for replying.But its not worked for me.I am going to post the Error with new changes in code.